# I'm trying to add a comment area that only shows up on a certain part and I'm getting an error: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, project, addeventlistener

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('songs').addEventListener('click', getSongs)
  commentSection()
  //getSongs()
})

function getSongs() {
  let info = document.getElementById('info')
  let songList = document.getElementById('song-list')
  info.innerHTML = ""
  songList.innerHTML = ""
    fetch('https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=K-Pop')
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
        data.results.map(song => { 
          //console.log(song)
          songList.innerHTML += `
            <li>
             <a href="#" data-name="${song.trackName}"
             data-id="${song.trackId}"> ${song.trackName} </a>
            </li>

          `
        })
        attachLinks()
    })
}

function attachLinks() {
  const songs = document.querySelectorAll('li a')
  songs.forEach(song => {
    song.addEventListener('click', displaySong)
  })
}

function displaySong(event) {
  //console.log(event.target)
  let a = event.target
  let songList = document.getElementById('song-list')
  let info = document.getElementById('info')
  songList.innerHTML= ""
  info.innerHTML = ""
  fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=${event.target.dataset.id}`)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
        data.results.map(song => { 
          //console.log(song)
            info.innerHTML += `
              <h1>${song.trackName}</h1>
              <h2>Artist Name:</h2>
              <p>${song.artistName}</p>
              <h3>Release Date:</h3>
              <p>${song.releaseDate}</p>

            <div id="comments">
              <h2>Write a comment!</h2>

              <form id="comment-form">
                <div class="field">
                    <input id="new-comment" type="text" placeholder="New Comment" />
                    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit"/>
                </div>
              </form>
            
              <div id="commentsContainer">
                <h3>Comments</h3>

              </div>
            </div>
            `
          })
    })
}

function commentSection() {
  const commentForm = document.getElementById('comment-form')
  const commentsContainer = document.getElementById('commentsContainer')
  
  commentForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const userInput = event.target.querySelector('#new-comment').value
    const commentPTag = document.createElement('p')
    commentPTag.innerHTML = userInput
    commentsContainer.innerHTML(commentPTag)
    commentForm.reset()
  })
}
```

I want it to only be on the part where it shows the song name, artist, and release date and not show up everywhere. I was told that `innerHTML` causes some problems with `addEventListener` so that might be the problem. My instructor suggested using `insertAdjacentHTML` but I'm not sure how  I would use that if I have multiple lines of code that I want to add?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users read [ask] for tips on forming questions that best enable the community to provide assistance.  This question is a bit vague-- you haven't shared which line is causing the problem.  Additionally, your question is worded such that it requires deep knowledge of your project that visitors will not possess.  I'd recommend creating a [mcve] and providing a clear explanation of what is not working and in what way it is failing to work.  At a glance, it sounds as though you are trying to add an event listener to a element that doesn't exist. Thanks, good luck!

Comment: Make sure your DOM elements exists before adding event listeners. You should be able to correctly debug from there. (i.e. ``const commentForm = document.getElementById('comment-form')
const commentsContainer = document.getElementById('commentsContainer')
  
commentForm && commentForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
``). I use optional chaining, but you'd have to ensure you have that enabled w/ es6 ``commentForm?.addEventListener(...``.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a JavaScript scope problem
instead of this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('songs').addEventListener('click', getSongs)
  commentSection()
  //getSongs()
})
```

try :

```
if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {
  document.getElementById('songs').addEventListener('click', getSongs);
  commentSection();
}
```